# Generating Django sitemap.xml: How to fix 'get_absolute_url' error

Tags: python, xml, django

I have a “BigPage” model that has an element called “pagename” that has unique set to True. I would like to use the django-sitemaps framework to generate, populate, and continuously update the sitemap.xml file every time a new BigPage model with a new “pagename” element is created by adding the URL `myapp.com/pagename` to my project’s sitemap.xml file. Here's my BigPage model:

```
class BigPage(models.Model):
    Pagename = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, unique=True, null=True) #they will enter this input into a form field to reserve their unique url at myapp.com/pagename
    PageNameOwner  = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True) #owner of page enters their name
    OwnerGender = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=(('male', 'Male'), ('female', 'Female')), blank=True, null=True) 
    PageViewsCounter = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=0)
    PageIsRemoved = models.BooleanField(default=False) #true if mods take down a person’s page

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Pagename
```

I have created the below sitemap.py file and placed it in the folder of my app where the BigPage model resides:

```
 class BigPageSitemap(Sitemap):
     changefreq = 'daily'
     priority = 0.5

     def items(self):
        return BigPage.objects.all()
```

Then, in the main project url.py file (not the app url.py file) I have added this:

```
sitemaps = {
'Name of Page':BigPageSitemap
}
```

To the urlpatterns element this:

```
url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap', {'sitemaps': sitemaps})
```

My app url.py has the following url pattern where if a term is entered in the URL field that matches a pagename element that can then be queried to retrieve a BigPage object then it loads that page, but if the entered URL is not equal to a pagename element, it will give the user a 404:

```
 url(r'^(?P<url_param>[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*)/$', views.view_for_all_BigPages, name='view_for_all_BigPages'),)
```

After all of this, no sitemap file seems to generate if I check the app folder or main project folder. If I go to myapp.com/sitemap.xml I get the following error:

```
'BigPage' object has no attribute 'get_absolute_url'
```

What things have I done wrong? I really appreciate any help. I’ve been trying for days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#a-simple-example):

> There is no location method in this example, but you can provide it in
>   order to specify the URL for your object. By default, location() calls
>   get_absolute_url() on each object and returns the result.

you didnot define `location()` method in your Sitemap class, thats why it is trying to call `get_absolute_url()` on your model. so you need to define `get_absolute_url()` in your model like this:

```
class BigPage(models.Model):
    Pagename = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, unique=True, null=True) 
    # ....

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Pagename

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('view_for_all_BigPages', kwargs={'url_param': self.Pagename})
```

by the way, model attributes are written in small letters, `pagename` rather than `Pagename`.

Comment: Wow, that worked amazingly. I'm really surprised the solution was so simple and I had toiled for many hours trying to figure out how the proper "get_absolute_url()" syntax was supposed to be. Thank you very much for the help. It works perfectly. You made my day.

Comment: One quick question though, where is the sitemap.xml file located and how exactly can I manipulate the directory location so that I can make sure the search engine crawlers find it in the correct/highest order directory. Thanks again.

Comment: @SwAvGuy you define the sitemap urls directly in main urls.py which means it is available directly after domain name like this: ``www.yourdomain.com/sitemap.xml``

Comment: I can see the sitemap at that location perfectly fine and also see it updating every time I create a new BigPage model just like I intend, but when I look into my file directories, there's no physical sitemap.xml file in either my app directory or main project directory or root of the project (where manage.py is located). Is that normal?

Comment: @SwAvGuy yes, this is normal. there wont be any physical xml file. it is shown dynamically by calling your sitemap class methods. and this way is much more efficient than creating a file and updating it.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. So I should be good then in terms of SEO for the project. Thanks for all your help. Saved me many hours of struggling. :)

Comment: @SwAvGuy yes, this is good enough for SEO. search engines will also call the url and they dont look for physical file. so you are fine :). have fun